# Запись данных из одного файла в начало (!) другого

Tags: файлы, java

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    String fileName1 = reader.readLine();
    String fileName2 = reader.readLine();

    byte[] b = new byte[1000];

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName2);
    RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(fileName1, "rw");

    randomAccessFile.seek(0);

    while(fileInputStream.available() > 0){
        int count = fileInputStream.read(b);
        randomAccessFile.write(b, 0, count);
    }

    fileInputStream.close();
    randomAccessFile.close();
    reader.close();
}
}
```

Проблема в том, что установки метки на позицию "0", данные из второго файла переписывают данные первого файла, а нужно, чтобы встали перед ними. Подскажите, как этого достичь?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вставка данных не поддерживается, так что надо делать так:

1. Прочитать данные файла №1 и куда то сохранить (в память/файл)
2. Записать данные из файла №2 в файл №1
3. Добавить в хвост полученного файла ранее сохраненные данные

Comment: По крайней мере для \*nix сценарий 

- скопировать файл-2 в файл-tmp

- дописать файл-1 в конец файл-tmp (после данных из файл-2)

- ПЕРЕИМЕНОВАТЬ файл-tmp в файл-1

короче на одно переписывание данных файла-1